# Unable to test Redis repository with @DataRedisTest annotated test class

Tags: redis, junit5, autowired, spring-boot-test, spring-repositories

I'm trying to write unit test for Redis repository of my spring boot application. But  the autowired repository object causes the exception below when I run the test case:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mycomp.myapi.repository.UserRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycomp.myapi.repository.UserRepositoryTest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at
```

@DataRedisTest annotation should autowire the repository object, but it doesn't. What is wrong or missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Spring boot version : 2.6.6

I use embedded Redis for testing. My maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My Embedded Redis configuration class is:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRedisConfiguration {

    private RedisServer redisServer;

    public TestRedisConfiguration() {
        this.redisServer = new RedisServer(6370);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }
  
}
```

And Embedded Redis settings at application.properties:

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6370
```

My Redis repository test class is:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataRedisTest
@Import(TestRedisConfiguration.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }


    @Test
    public void saveUser() {

        User user = prepareUser();

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        User foundUser = userRepository.findById(savedUser.getUserId()).get();
        
        assertThat(foundUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(savedUser.getEmail());

    }
    

    @Test
    public void findByEmail() {

        User user = prepareUser();

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        User foundUser = userRepository.findByEmail("xxx@gmail.com").get();
        
        assertThat(foundUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo(savedUser.getEmail());

    }
    
    private User prepareUser() {
        
        User user = new User();
        
        user.setUserId("62d322ddf9f5e01864bed242");
        user.setEmail("xx@gmail.com");
        
        return user;
        
    }
}
```

I also check the context with a test class as blow:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class MyApiApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```